# foundation() is not a function error during Karma UT (Angular 5 + Foundation)

Tags: angular, zurb-foundation, karma-jasmine

I recently upgraded my angular4 project to angular 5 project. When running the app, Foundation modal can open as intended. However, when running UT using Karma, the UT always complains about:

`Failed: $(...).foundation is not a function`

Tried the following things already:

- Included foundation in `tsconfig.spec.ts`
- Included foundation in files in `karma.conf.js`
- Included foundation in `test.ts` as well

and the closest thing is this workaround `Foundation.addToJquery($);` that is mentioned [in Foundation forum discussion here](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/10336). However, this works for all `foundation()` except `foundation('open')`.

I created a simple app here for everyone to reproduce: [my-app1](https://github.com/texasinstrument/my-app1).
You just need to run `npm run test` and you can reproduce the issue. I didn't have this issue in angular4.

Anyone having the same issue in angular5?
I am using Angular 5 and Foundation `6.4.3`.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same problem. I was using following declaration for initializing foundation and it was failing.

> ngAfterViewInit() {
>   $(this.el.nativeElement.ownerDocument).foundation(); }

I changed that to:

> ngAfterViewInit() { $(document).foundation(); }

and it solved the issue.

Also I have declared $ as :

> declare var $:any;

Hope it works for you too!